# Building 'multi interface' using wxWidget

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have read several demos given by the wxWidget package, but none of them is 'multi interface'. Say I want to write a simple game using wxWidget, I may need a menu interface, a game interface, a setting interface and so on. My question is how can I build them into a single App? Do I need several wxFrame and Close and Show them from time to time? (However when I close it the application is terminated) Or is there an another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed have multiple frames, but by default closing the *last* frame terminates the application. You can use [SetExitOnFrameDelete(false)](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_app.html#aceb948ece9ba286f738ec3379a18bc52) to prevent this from happening or just make sure that you create the new/next frame (without necessarily showing it) before closing the previous one.

It is also possible to simply show different contents inside the same frame, e.g. by creating and showing different `wxPanel`s inside it. [wxSimplebook](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_simplebook.html) can be useful for this.